# Lost connectivity after iptables change

Tags: iptables

I attempted to add a couple web ports to iptables and in doing so lost the ability to resolve any external address.  I have a working SSH session open and can get to the box easily if needed.

Here's the current iptables config:

[user@boxen]# iptables --line-numbers -n -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 /* 100 allow http and https access */ state NEW 
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 22 /* 100 ssh 22 */ 
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

and cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:196]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "100 allow http and https access" -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --ports 22 -m comment --comment "100 ssh 22" -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Sep 25 14:20:02 2013
```

I can't ping the gateway or anything else.  I am able to ping the gateway on another box in the same rack.  I was able to ping gateway prior to my botched iptables update.

What's wrong with this config?

Comment: Please describe exactly what you changed.

Comment: Please add `-v` to your iptables command: `iptables --line-numbers -v -n -L` Otherwise it doesn't list interface restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you dropped all incoming traffic that is not:

1. TCP ports 80 or 443
2. TCP port 22
3. From localhost

Most likely, you intended to have a rule along the lines of:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Right now your DNS replies (typically UDP source port 53) are being dropped. As are your ICMP echo replies (ping responses).